# VBScript Compilation Error - Expected Sub

Tags: vbscript, avaya

I have the below script that keeps receiving

> Compilation Error Line 16 - Expected Sub

I'm not seeing what's causing this.

This script is run by **acscript** for an Avaya phone system. It's probable the `## cvs_cmd_begin` and `## cvs_cmd_end` are replaced with something else by the engine.

```
'SERVERNAME=123.45.67.89
Public Sub Main()
'## cvs_cmd_begin
' =========================================================
'  ERROR ERROR ERROR
'  If you're having trouble running a script make sure it's Encoding = UTF-8 (use Notepad++)
' =========================================================
'   On Error Resume Next

    SaveFolder = "K:\Telephony\ACD Automation\AutoReport.AgentInterval\Daily 20200124\"
    SaveFile = "Agent.Interval_20200124_12345.txt"

   cvsSrv.Reports.ACD = 1
   Set Info = cvsSrv.Reports.Reports("Historical\Designer\A.Agent Interval")

    If Info Is Nothing Then
        Exit
    Else
        b = cvsSrv.Reports.CreateReport(Info,Rep)

        If b Then
            Rep.TimeZone = "default"    
            Rep.SetProperty "Agent", "12345"
            Rep.SetProperty "Date", "1/24/2020"
            Rep.SetProperty "Times", "07:00-20:45"

            b = Rep.ExportData(SaveFolder & SaveFile, 9, 0, False, True, True)
                Rep.Quit
                Set Rep = Nothing
        End If
    End If

    Set Info = Nothing
'## cvs_cmd_end
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I just commented out the outer If block and the Set Info = at the end and it works. Not really a problem for me if the script fails as it just means the report returned no data so...

Comment: `Exit` what on line 16? `Exit` is always followed by what it is you are exiting.

Comment: @Mark yep, [answered that 30 minutes earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59911699/timeline).

Comment: But you didn't make the point of actually looking at line 16.

Comment: @Mark Really? Didn’t realise the `Exit` statement appears more than once in the code, oh yeah, it doesn’t.

Comment: The person who posted should have READ the error message. It is quite explicit as to what and where.

Comment: @mark agree, the error is pretty self explanatory if you realise that `Exit` is not a valid statement in VBScript. It tells you the line where it expects `Sub` so not a big ask to work out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of the [`Exit` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//t234253x%28v%3dvs.85%29) without the accompanying keyword. There are five flavours of the `Exit` statement that depend on the context.

1. `Exit Do`
2. `Exit For`
3. `Exit Function`
4. `Exit Sub`
5. `Exit Property`

In this instance the code is trying to exit the Sub Procedure if the `Info` object variable is not set. The fix is to change line 16 from

```
Exit
```

to

```
Exit Sub
```